# AFNetworking NetworkObserver not working Correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetworking NetworkObserver To check Internet Connection Continuously. I want to update ui on basis of internet connection. For that I have added following observer in app delegate:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

then in each viewController I had added :

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %ld %@",(long)status, AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
        int intRechable = status;
        if (intRechable == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Connection lost");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Connected");
        }
}];
```

Problem is Some time it works and some time not.
I had checked some answer they are mentioning set time delay. But still it not working alway's.

Note : I observe that, the controller which don't have web service call, on that controller it's working good (even on simulator as well!). Is there any relation between this?

Comment: Have you checked in device?

Comment: Yes, using 6 plus to test. Following are Scenarios : 
1. If I am on same screen if Internet lost it don't show any response, but If I move to other screen it give not internet.
2. The scenario I mentioned is not frequent but this is main issue.
3. Some of the screen it works perfectly. 
I am just stuck on this. I am going to implement another way for it, I will let you know if it works. Happy Coding.

Comment: Ohhh, It was my mistake I am not checking status flag correctly. Instead of putting status into intRechable variable either change intReachable variable to long or directly check status by typecasting it to long with integer, it solved my problem.